# Python - Counting Letter Frequency in a String

Tags: python, string, frequency

I want to write my each string's letter frequencies. My inputs and expected outputs are like this.

```
"aaaa" -> "a4"
"abb" -> "a1b2"
"abbb cc a" -> "a1b3 c2 a1"
"bbbaaacddddee" -> "b3a3c1d4e2"
"a   b" -> "a1 b1"
```

I found [this solution](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-frequency-of-each-character-in-string/) but it gives the frequencies in random order. How can I do this?

Comment: What have you done? Please show us your code.

Comment: You can sort it right?

Comment: @Ruthvik I can use `.sort()` I know, but the 4th example is risky for that

Comment: @asnerdyasSteveWozniak I've written source of the code which I found, but I didn't do as I expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this satisfy your needs?

```
from itertools import groupby
s = "bbbaaac ddddee aa"

groups = groupby(s)
result = [(label, sum(1 for _ in group)) for label, group in groups]
res1 = "".join("{}{}".format(label, count) for label, count in result)
# 'b3a3c1 1d4e2 1a2'

# spaces just as spaces, do not include their count
import re
re.sub(' [0-9]+', ' ', res1)
'b3a3c1 d4e2 a2'
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, it is a little bit trickier that it looks at first. For example, it does look that `"bbbaaacddddee" -> "b3a3c1d4e2"` needs the count results to be outputted in the order of appearance in the passed string:

```
import re

def unique_elements(t):
    l = []
    for w in t:
        if w not in l:
            l.append(w)
    return l

def splitter(s):
    res = []
    tokens = re.split("[ ]+", s)
    for token in tokens:
        s1 = unique_elements(token) # or s1 = sorted(set(token))
        this_count = "".join([k + str(v) for k, v in list(zip(s1, [token.count(x) for x in s1]))])
        res.append(this_count)
    return " ".join(res)

print(splitter("aaaa"))
print(splitter("abb")) 
print(splitter("abbb cc a"))
print(splitter("bbbaaacddddee")) 
print(splitter("a   b"))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
a4
a1b2
a1b3 c2 a1
b3a3c1d4e2
a1 b1
```

If the order of appearance is not a real deal, you can disregard the `unique_elements` function and simply substitute something like `s1 = sorted(set(token))` within `splitter`, as indicated in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> here is you answer
> ```

```
test_str = "here is your answer"
res = {}
list=[]
list=test_str.split()
# print(list)
for a in list:
    res={}
    for keys in a:
        res[keys] = res.get(keys, 0) + 1
    for key,value in res.items():
        print(f"{key}{value}",end="")
    print(end=" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to iterate every character in every word.
This is an alternate solution. (If you don't want to use itertools, that looked pretty tidy.)

```
def word_stats(data: str=""):
    all = []
    for word in data.split(" "):
        res = []
        while len(word)>0:
            res.append(word[:1] + str(word.count(word[:1])))
            word = word.replace(word[:1],"")
        res.sort()
        all.append("".join(res))
    return " ".join(all)

print(word_stats("asjssjbjbbhsiaiic ifiaficjxzjooro qoprlllkskrmsnm mmvvllvlxjxj jfnnfcncnnccnncsllsdfi"))
print(word_stats("abbb cc a"))
print(word_stats("bbbaaacddddee"))
```

This would output:

```
c5d1f3i1j1l2n7s2  
a1b3 c2 a1  
a3b3c1d4e2
```